# How to befriend real-time processes and OOM killer?

Tags: linux, out-of-memory, real-time

```
$ mlockall schedtool -R -p 4 -e ionice -c1 mplayer -really-quiet whatever.ogg
$ mempig
Killed
```

Mplayer

- is running with realtime scheduling priority
- is running with realtime IO priority
- have all it's pages locked in memory

but still "chops" when I start OOM-killer bait.

What more can be done to make real-time processes real-time even when OOM? (expect of "vm.overcommit_memory=2", of course)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so I'm not going to go on and on, but, look into /proc/pid/oom_adj and /proc/pid/oom_score

Comment: Not an answer for this question. The problem is not that wrong processes are chosen for killing, but that when calculating all that things it "stops the world" making interruption in all (even real-time) tasks.

Comment: Aaah... so by 'chops' you mean interrupts the processing of mplayer such that you get skips/pauses or something?  I assumed you meant it killed mplayer.

Comment: Yes. It means the playing is not fluent.